# Add even numbers using one dimensional array of size 10 in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, undefined-behavior

program to calculate sum of all even elements from one dimensional
array of size 10.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    int i,count=0;
    int a[10]; //one dimensional array with size 10
    for(i=0;i<=11;i++){
        a[i]=i; //assigning values to array
        if(i%2==0){
            count=count+a[i]; //add even numbers
        }
    }
    printf("%d",count); //output
}
```

I expected output to be 30 but actual output is 20.

Comment: `a` has a size of `10`, so `a[i]=i` is out of bounds for when `i` is `10` and `11`. But what do you need the array for anyway? Just do `for(i=0;i<=11;i+=2) count=+=i;`

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=11;i++)` -- This mreans that `i` will be 11 at some time, which is two beyond the array bounds. Besides, you don't need an array to sum the even numbers up to 10. You don't even need a loop.

Comment: thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
for(i=0;i<=11;i++){
```

invokes undefined behavior because within the loop there is an attempt to access memory outside the array.

If an array has `N` elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, N)`. So rewrite the loop like

```
for(i=0;i < 10;i++){
```

The reason of the error is using magic numbers. Use named constants instead of magic numbers. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int count = 0;
    int a[N];

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = i;

        if ( i % 2 == 0 )
        {
            count += a[i];
        }
    }

    printf( "%d\n", count ); 

    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a[10] and a[11] which is undefined.